# How to change orientation from Portrait to All (Landscape/Portrait both) for the single ContentPage in xamarin.forms for IOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, device-orientation

I want to change the orientation of the single page. My whole application should be run in portrait but I want to make one page as Landscape/portrait (both).

**I have taken reference from below links**

http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2017/05/force-landscape-or-portrait-for-single.html

**Code is working fine in Android but not in IOS.**

AppDelegate.cs

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, [Transient] UIWindow forWindow)
{
    var mainPage = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;

    if (mainPage is CartoonDetail_demo2 ||
            (mainPage is NavigationPage && ((NavigationPage)mainPage).CurrentPage is CartoonDetail_demo2) ||
            (mainPage.Navigation != null && mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault() is CartoonDetail_demo2))
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
}
```

**But this condition is never going to be true in any case. Eventually I can not get the page from navigation stack.**

**So, I use easy way to do the same thing,**

I want to make "CartoonDetail_demo2" this page as Landscape/Portrait.

1. In OnAppearing() method of the "CartoonDetail_demo2" page I have set one flag as true.
2. And OnDisappering() method of the "CartoonDetail_demo2" page I have set one flag as false.
3. use this flag in AppDelegate.cs.

> ```
> public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask 
> GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, [Transient] 
> UIWindow forWindow)
> {
>     if (AppConstants.IsOrientationAll)
>     {
>       return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
>     }
>     return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
>  }
> ```

**Now, Condition become true whenever I go to the page "CartoonDetail_demo2".**

**But It is not working and my page is always in Portrait Orientation**.

4. When I simply call this method without any condition then whole application is going in "All" (Landscape/Portrait) orientation.

   public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, [Transient] UIWindow forWindow)
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
   }
5. By default, My whole application in Portrait Orientation.

I have also tried few other demo but none of are going to working

https://xamarindevelopervietnam.wordpress.com/2017/05/23/how-to-rotate-specific-page-in-xamarin-forms/

**should I use the plugin Plugin.DeviceOrientation?**

Answer (score 0):

> in AppDelegate.cs

```
public bool allowRotation;
```

And rewrite the method

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, [Transient] UIWindow forWindow)
{
   if(allowRotation==true)
   {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
   }

   else
   {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
   }
}
```

Then you can call the following method in  dependency service

> in iOS

```
public class OrientationService : IOrientationService
{
    public void Landscape()
    {
        AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
        appDelegate.allowRotation = true;

        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));   
    }

    public void Portrait()
    {
        AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
        appDelegate.allowRotation = true;

        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
    }
}
```

> in Android

```
public class OrientationService : IOrientationService
{
    public void Landscape()
    {
        ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    }

    public void Portrait()
    {
        ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    }
}
```

For more detail you can refer this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925584/force-landscape-mode-in-single-page-in-xamarin-ios/52940622#52940622).