# Xamarin Forms app not changing orientation on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xam.Forms app which is working fine on iOS and Android with one exception. All screens except one are portrait. When this one screen shows, it show rotate to landscape. It works fine on android.

On iOS, it fails to change. The `info.plist` file has all orientations enabled. As I want only this one screen to be portrait, I have in the AppDelegate class an override that ensures everytrhing is portrait except one.

The override is this

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
    {
        var mainPage = Shell.Current?.CurrentPage;
        if (mainPage != null)
        {
            if (mainPage is IDCardPage)
            {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
            }
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
```

A break point for the landscape is hit, but there is no rotation. According to the Apple docs, this is all I should need to do to rotate a view

Comment: It's rotation enabled on the iPhone?

Comment: In the info.plist all the orientations are ticked, so yes

Comment: And I guess you are doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925584/force-landscape-mode-in-single-page-in-xamarin-ios) for the return code?

Comment: Well, I'm not using DI to do it. I'm using the MessagingCenter for android and a custom renderer for iOS for the ViewController. It looks like I need to add ViewWillAppear in there to make this work

Comment: @Nodoid I mean on the physical phone [enable this button](https://cdn4syt-solveyourtech.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/how-to-rotate-screen-on-iphone-7-2.jpg)